# Determine if point is inside triangle in 3D

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, intersection, raytracing

I am looking for acknowledgement on my perception of a method regarding determining whether a point is located inside a triangle or not in 3D.

Given a ray in the form R(t) = e + td and a set of three points T = {V0, V1, V2} that forms a triangle in three dimensions, I know how to find the parametic equation for the plane that the three points form and how to determine if the ray intersects this plane or not. Lastly, if it intersects, I want to know if the intersection point actually is within the bounds of the triangles edges.

Please see my picture below.

[image]

What I am thinking is that I can calculate the dot product between each edge vector and the vector that goes from the first edge in the edge vector towards the point and check if they are all positive. Like this:

[image]

If that is the case, the point should be inside the triangle. Right? Isn't this kind of the same method used for determining backfaces in computer graphics?

Comment: I constructed an example to test the method and it seems like it works.. at least in that case. I am still looking for a definitive answer.
The triangle I made up is made of the vertices { P0, P1, P2 } = { (0,0,0) , (5,0,5) , (5,0,0) } and the points I let be w = (3, -5, 0) och u = (5, 5, 5) to form a line that I knew would intersect the triangle at some point.

Comment: this is incorrect; the dot product check only works if the boundary is a right-angle

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah , If I let the vectors go counter-clockwise, exactly as I described in my text and in the image above, I can't see why it should be a problem? Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: the dot product is only negative if the angle is greater than 90 degrees; obviously the angles in a triangle can be smaller than that, so you could potentially be detecting points _just_ outside the sides of the triangle, but also missing out those inside an _obtuse_ triangle

Comment: plenty of resources on the net, see here for example: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah thank you for your replies. Do you mind looking at the links in my comments to the answer below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In graphics, people usually use barycentric coordinates. In your case, `P` can be described as `P = aV0 + bV1 + cV2`, where `a + b + c = 1` . `P` is inside if and only if `0 <= a, b, c <= 1`.

If the triangles formed by `v1, P, v2` has the area `S1`, the triangle formed by `P, v0, v2` has the area of `S2`, and `P, V0, V1` has the area of `S3`. Then `a = S1/S`, `b = S2/S` and `c = S3/S`, where `S` is the area of triangle `V0, V1, V2`.

To find the area of `S = 1/2||(V0-V1)creosspdoruct(V0-V2)||`.

You can check out the [tutorial](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~amahdavi/pmwiki-2.2.8/uploads/Site/RayTracing3.ppt) that I put on my website.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will definitely check out your tutorial! Do you mind having a look at the third method on this page http://totologic.blogspot.se/2014/01/accurate-point-in-triangle-test.html
What is different from this method and the one I proposed?

Comment: Also, I found this: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution
Quote: "to find out if P is inside the triangle we can test if the dot product of the vector along the edge and the vector defined by the first vertex of the tested edge and P is positive (meaning P is on the left side of the edge). If P is on the left of all three edges, then P is inside the triangle."

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same setting? int he third method, you should not find the dot product of v0v1 and v0p. It seems that you need to find the dot product of left-orthogonal to v0v1 as the tutorial describes:For that, first we need to consider  the 3 vectors v1, v2 and v3 that are respectively left-orthogonal to [p1, p2], [p2, p3] and [p3, p1] :

v1 = <y2 - y1, -x2 + x1>
v2 = <y3 - y2, -x3 + x2>
v3 = <y1 - y3, -x1 + x3>

Comment: in the second link that you sent, you also need to find the cross product of v0p and vov1

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. So instead of doing what I proposed, I calculate the cross product between each edge vector and the vector that goes from the first edge in the edge vector towards the point and after that I calculate the dot product between the result of the cross product and the plane normal..?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little bit late to the party (sorry), but here's my take on this:

I used to do ray-tracing in the 80's.  At the time I came up with a solution that is rather similar to what you are discussing.

The idea is that if a point is always on the right side of an observer walking the edges of the triangle clockwise, then the point is inside the triangle.

For this we need a test to see if the point is on the right side of each edge. A dot product would be nice, but as it was pointed out, a dot product will give you a cos value.  What you want is a sin, so you can reject points that have a negative test. This is why people tend to use a cross product instead.  But a cross product requires a lot more computation that a dot product (in the 80's that was really important!)

But we can transform the cos in a sin by a simple 90 deg rotation! So, instead of computing the dot product with the edge, we compute it with a line rotated 90 deg from the edge in the plane of the polygon.

At first that seems like a lot of trouble, but not if we work in one of the main planes. XY, YZ or XZ.  So instead of working in 3D in the triangle's plane, lets work in 2D in one of the main planes. If a point is inside a polygon in 3D, it will also be inside it's projection on the 2D plane.  Of course, if the polygon is parallel to one of the main planes we may have a problem if we project on the wrong plane.

So, to select this plane, just look at the triangle's normal and select the plane that is closer to the triangle's plane.  If the X component is the biggest, we use the YZ plane etc...  Also, the sign of that component will tell us if the projected polygon will be clockwise or counterclockwise.

In one of these 2D planes, a 90 deg rotation of an edge is just swapping the values with a sign change on one of these.

For example, in the XY plane, the edge between V0 and V1 is:

V0V1x = v1x - v0x

V0V1y = V1y - v0y

the vector between V0 and P is:

V0Px = Px - V0x

V0Py = Py - V0y

A -90 deg. rotation of the edge give is given us x' = y and y' = -x ;

So the scalar product we compute for the first edge will be

Scalar = (Px - V0x) * (V1y - V0y) + (Py - V0y) * (V0x - V1x)

If that value is < 0, then the point is not inside.

You do this with the 2 other edges and you have your "inside" test.

In my solution as a pre-processing I compute a value giving me the maximum normal direction and sign for each triangle.  After that I use that value to know in what plane I want to compute my intersection. (A negative normal component makes me switch the "clockwise" direction of the triangle).

The test to know if the point is inside the polygon takes:

- 1 "direction" test with the maximum normal value (a switch with 6 cases, XY, XZ or YZ, positive or negative)
- 3 "edge" tests with 4 subtractions and 2 multiplications each and 1 test.

You only do the "edge" test 3 times if the point is inside the polygon.  If not it may be rejected after the first or second edge...

So, knowing if a point is inside a triangle will take from 8 to 22 operations.

Most of the solutions I see nowadays seem to use more operations than that!

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve

```
E + t.D = a.V0 + b.V1 + c.V2
```

where

```
t, a, b, c >= 0, a + b + c = 1
```

Using `c = 1 - a - b`, you get a 3x3 linear system (decompose for `x`, `y`, `z`)

```
a.(V0 - V2) + b.(V1 - V2) - t.D = E - V2
```

that you can solve for `t`, `a`, `b`, then `c` and check positiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot products to determine if a point is in a triangle.  First find the projection of the test point onto each edge.  The sign of the dot product is only meaningful at right angles, and the projection will give you a right angle.

For triangle `a`, `b`, `c` and point `p` compute `m` and `s` for each edge.  `m` is the point where `p` projects onto edge `ab`.

```
m = (p - a) • (b - a) / |b - a|² * (b - a) + a
s = (p - m) • (c - m)
```

If `s` is positive, then `p` and `c` are on the same side of `ab`.  Repeat this test for each edge.  If `p` and the opposing vertex are on the same side of each edge, then `p` is in the triangle.

This plane splitting technique is often done with cross products, but it might be more efficient this way.

For `|b - a|²` you can use `(b - a) • (b - a)` if length squared is unavailable.